# Guarantee ResourceQuota in a Namespace

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running a cluster that is shared across teams and I'd like to guarantee each team a minimum amount of resources, especially memory.

Following the [instructions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/quota-memory-cpu-namespace/) I've tried using the following on their namespace:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: mem-quota
spec:
  hard:
    requests.memory: 8Gb
```

However from reading more docs, it turns out this doesn't guarantee they have 8Gb of memory for their pods.  It just means the sum of their pods `requests.memory` value can't exceed 8Gb.  It's possible that they could have 8Gb set as above, only be using 4Gb and be unable to create a new pod if the cluster was maxed out elsewhere and the new pod couldn't be scheduled.

Also for example, I can create a `ResourceQuota` with a `requests.memory` value of 16Gi on a cluster with only 8Gi of total memory.

Is there anyway to guarantee a team a fixed amount of memory for only their use?

Answer (score 0):

> It just means the sum of their pods requests.memory value can't
> exceed 8Gb

Yes, this is the logic for ResourceQuota. From [Understanding Resource Quotas:](https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/)

Resource quotas work like this:

> - Users put compute resource requests on their pods. **The sum of all resource requests across all pods in the same namespace must not
>   exceed any hard resource limit in any Resource Quota document for the
>   namespace.** Note that we used to verify Resource Quota by taking the
>   sum of resource limits of the pods, but this was altered to use
>   resource requests. Backwards compatibility for those pods previously
>   created is preserved because pods that only specify a resource limit
>   have their resource requests defaulted to match their defined limits.
>   The user is only charged for the resources they request in the
>   Resource Quota versus their limits because the request is the minimum
>   amount of resource guaranteed by the cluster during scheduling. For
>   more information on over commit, see compute-resources.
> - If creating a pod would cause the namespace to exceed any of the limits specified in the the Resource Quota for that namespace, then
>   the request will fail with HTTP status code 403 FORBIDDEN.
> - If quota is enabled in a namespace and the user does not specify requests on the pod for each of the resources for which quota is
>   enabled, then the POST of the pod will fail with HTTP status code 403
>   FORBIDDEN. Hint: Use the LimitRange admission controller to force
>   default values of limits (then resource requests would be equal to
>   limits by default, see admission controller) before the quota is
>   checked to avoid this problem.

---

However article expand a bit a cases, where you need divide resources separately. And this is not something already implemented..

***Quota and Cluster Capacity:***
Sometimes more complex policies may be desired, such as:

- ***proportionally divide total cluster resources among several teams.***
- allow each tenant to grow resource usage as needed, but have a generous limit to prevent accidental resource exhaustion.
- detect demand from one namespace, add nodes, and increase quota.

***Such policies could be implemented using ResourceQuota as a building-block, by writing a 'controller' which watches the quota usage and adjusts the quota hard limits of each namespace according to other signals.***

---

I expect you need write custom logic in own controller.

Please take a look also at [How To Force Kubernetes Namespaces To Have ResourceQuotas Using OPA](https://www.magalix.com/blog/how-to-force-kubernetes-namespaces-to-have-resourcequotas-defined-using-opa)